# Large file synchronisation

Tags: directory, network-attached-storage, synchronization, bittorrent

I have a big directory that takes about 600GB with tens of thousands files. I need to synchronize it with my Qnap NAS. I tries BitTorrent Sync, but speed is very slow and it will take about a month for such transfer. Speed is about 10KB per second. If I copy it over AFP from my Mac the speed is about 50MB per second. Can I copy it over AFP and say for BitTorrent that these files are synced and same? If no, is there any other faster ways of syncing?

Answer (score 3):

Getting the initial copy is the hard part, perhaps an external drive and sneakernet is best. Then you should consider rsync for keeping it up-to-date. Rsync may even be a good option for the initial sync too.

Comment: I'd go with rsync too.

Comment: +1 for `rsync`.  Bittorrent sync is overkill when you're only transferring data in one direction and on the same network. Plus it's a closed source product. `rsync` will always be free.